# C# Round Color to Colors in a list

Tags: c#, colors, rounding

I have a list of colors in HEX format:

```
String[] validcolors = new String[]
{
    "0055A5",
    "101010",
    "E4D200",
    "FFFFFF",
    "006563",
    "A97B3E",
    "B80000",
    "6E3391",
    "D191C3",
    "D68200",
    "60823C",
    "AA8D73",
    "73A1B8",
    "6E6D6E",
    "00582C",
    "604421"
};
```

And a color object:

```
Color c = ...
```

I want to find the color that is closest to `c` in `validcolors`. Can somebody help me out? My initial idea was 'closest by RGB value', but whatever works is fine.

Comment: Closest by RGB value is what I was trying to implement.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I will delete my answer, but keep this string to color conversion: `Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(s.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber), int.Parse(...`

Comment: **Doing this in the RGB color model is likely to produce some awfully *strange* results.** They won't look like matches at all, at least not to the human eye. If you want to do this the *right* way, you should convert the color to either the HSV/HSB or HSL color space. Yes, they're different, but in this case, it doesn't really matter which. They simulate human perception of colors much better. You can convert back to RGB once you get the match.

Comment: hah, yes I noticed from implementing manji's answer... I'll modify it to use HSV, and post the results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would think of transforming the hex to .NET color then calculating somr sort of distance ((x2-x1)²+(y2-y1)²) and taking the closest using this distance:

```
string closestColor = "";
double diff = 200000; // > 255²x3

foreach(string colorHex in validColors)
{
    Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#"+colorHex);
    if(diff > (diff = (c.R - color.R)²+(c.G - color.G)²+(c.B - color.B)²))
        closestColor = colorHex;
}

return closestColor;
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use this method (which works perfectly) it produces strange results, like Cody said. Like he suggested, modifying the method to use HSV fixed the problem.

Comment: How did you modified it to use HSV?

Answer (score 2):

The distance between two colors depends on the color model you are using. [See this article in the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model) so until we know what model you prefer we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a (verbose) method using HSB.

```
float targetHue = c.GetHue();
float targetSat = c.GetSaturation();
float targetBri = c.GetBrightness();

string closestColor = "";
double smallestDiff = double.MaxValue;

foreach (string colorHex in validcolors)
{
    Color currentColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + colorHex);
    float currentHue = currentColor.GetHue();
    float currentSat = currentColor.GetSaturation();
    float currentBri = currentColor.GetBrightness();

    double currentDiff = Math.Pow(targetHue - currentHue, 2) + Math.Pow(targetSat - currentSat, 2) + Math.Pow(targetBri - currentBri, 2);

    if (currentDiff < smallestDiff)
    {
        smallestDiff = currentDiff;
        closestColor = colorHex;
    }
}

return closestColor;
```